# Does not return the correct format with this code

Tags: php, sql, datetime

When saving a date in a 'date' field, you need make sure the date is formatted properly. The correct format is YYYY-MM-DD.

Complete the function to convert a passed date into a SQL safe date and return the results using the following requirements:

```
<?php

function convert_date_sql($date) {
  $date = strtotime($date);
  $date = date('yyyy-mm-dd',$date);
  return $date;

}
```

Comment: https://eval.in/792674

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the correct date format string.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d',$date);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: If this is an answer, mark it as such by ticking it. It is also good courtesy to upvote the one who answered your question(clicking the up arrow to give points)... You also need to revise your question to be clearer and of better quality

Answer (score 0):

see php date manual for format : http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

your code should be

```
$date = date('Y-m-d',$date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your date format conversion is worng. Use the below format to convert date

```
$date = date('Y-m-d',$date);
```